Mouseflow heat map is not loading in the Digital Experience site in Saleforce
Mouseflow Heatmap is not loading in the Digital Experience site in Saleforce.The site has been added as trusted site.When the HeatMap Live is loaded it does not loads as expected and following errors are logged in the console
Error: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document'
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')

